# Checkbox Selection in Kendo Grid Wrapper

Tags: vue.js, kendo-ui, grid, telerik

I've added kendo-grid like this:
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-vue-ui/components/grid/selection/#toc-checkbox-selection
But when I investigate my source code under console I don't see tags "id" and "for"

```html
<td role="gridcell">
  <input class="k-checkbox" data-role="checkbox" aria-label="Select row" aria-checked="false" type="checkbox">
  <label class="k-checkbox-label k-no-text"></label>
</td>
```

Comment: What is the question ? Are you looking to programmatically select a row or respond to a row selection ?

Comment: I'm using kendo UI vue.js from the box. Their example isn't work.
```html
<kendo-grid-column :selectable="true" :width="60"></kendo-grid-column>
```

Comment: sorry it was unfortunatly question... I've updated kendo.all.js and now it works.